# A clarification about calculating the Lyapunov exponent in R using Kantz/Rosenstein method

Tags: r, calculation

I was trying to estimate the the robustness of the estimation of Lyapunov exponent using the lyap_k function (part of the tseriesChaos) package and I wrote the following code to create a spiral and trying to see how changing the radius (eps) affected the estimation of the exponent.

According to the documentation, eps is the radius where to find nearest neighbours.
My spiral was contained in a 1.0 * 1.0 box, so I was expecting to see values increasingly close to 0 when the radius > 1. My rationale was that I am tracking the distance between neighbours in cloud of points that is larger than my trajectory, I should detect a smaller or zero expansion rate, and a close to zero Lyapunov exponent.
However the result is always the same (0.0607375)

Is there a flaw in my rationale or I am choosing the wrong set of parameters?
Thanks!

```
library(tseriesChaos)

#Create a spiral
t=1:100
s = t*sin(2*pi*t/20)
s=s/abs(max(s)-min(s))
plot(t,s)

s.emb=embedd(s,m = 2,d=5)
plot(s.emb,type='l')

#Running 4 calculations of lyap_k using different values of the radius (eps)
#Using 2 dimensions, delay = 5, Theiler window = 4, 10 reference points, tracked over 20 steps.

output=lyap_k(s,m=2,d=5,t=4, ref=10, k = 2, eps=0.1, s=20)
plot(output)
lyap(output,0,5)[[2]]

output=lyap_k(s,m=2,d=5,t=4, ref=10, k = 2, eps=1, s=20)
plot(output)
lyap(output,0,5)[[2]]

output=lyap_k(s,m=2,d=5,t=4, ref=10, k = 2, eps=10, s=20)
plot(output)
lyap(output,0,5)[[2]]

output=lyap_k(s,m=2,d=5,t=4, ref=10, k = 2, eps=20, s=20)
plot(output)
lyap(output,0,5)[[2]]
```